# Cassandra cql comparator type counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, cql

i want to use the following code for updating a field...

```
@@db.execute("UPDATE user_count SET counters = counters + #{val} WHERE cid = 1 ")
```

First time i tried that i got the following fail:
CassandraCQL::Error::InvalidRequestException: invalid operation for non commutative columnfamily user_count
I found out that i have to use the comparator counter, but i cant find how i can setup that with the cassandra-cql gem... does anybody know how i can get this to work?
below there is my code that does not work ...

```
@@db.execute("CREATE COLUMNFAMILY user_count(cid varchar PRIMARY KEY, counters counter) with comparator = counter " )
@@db.execute("INSERT INTO user_count (cid, counters) VALUES (?,?)", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set default_validation=CounterColumnType instead of comparator.

```
@@db.execute("CREATE COLUMNFAMILY user_count(cid varchar PRIMARY KEY, counters counter) with default_validation=CounterColumnType")
@@db.execute("update user_count set counters = counters + 1 where cid = 1")
```

You must use 'update' to change the counter value, there is no insert syntax for counters (in CQL update and insert do the same thing so you can [create new rows using update](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/references/cql/UPDATE#description)).

Currently you cannot have counters and non-counters in the same column family (from the [wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Counters): "A column family either contains only counters, or no counters at all.")

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, i tried that but i get the following fail... <br/> CassandraCQL::Error::InvalidRequestException: default_validation_class is not a valid keyword argument for CREATE COLUMNFAMILY
<br/> do you know why this happens? the gem version is cassandra-cql 1.0.2 and cassandra  version is 1.0.6

Comment: Sorry, it is just default_validation instead of default_validation_class. I corrected the answer.