# Composite keys and counter. I can create the column family but cant fill it

Tags: cql

I understood a counter family could have keys of any kind. Are composite keys unsupported?

```
 cqlsh:goh_master> create columnfamily balance (kind ascii, corporation_id ascii, amount  counter, primary key ( kind,corporation_id) ) with compact storage;
 cqlsh:goh_master> insert into balance(kind,corporation_id,amount) values ('c',103,123456789);
 Bad Request: invalid operation for commutative columnfamily balance
 cqlsh:goh_master> create columnfamily balance (kind ascii, corporation_id ascii, amount counter, primary key ( kind,corporation_id) ) with compact storage;
 cqlsh:goh_master> insert into balance(kind,corporation_id,amount) values ('c',103,123456789);
 Bad Request: invalid operation for commutative columnfamily balance
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by myself thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813211/cassandra-cql-comparator-type-counter?rq=1).
You cant insert into counters nor just set.
You must always use set counter =counter +n syntax:

```
cqlsh:goh_master> update balance set amount=amount+12 where kind='c' and corporation_id = 103;
```

worked like a charm