# Cassandra CQL: counter column creation and modification

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am trying to create a counter column through Java but I am getting an error when running it.
I am using CQL 3.0.0 and Cassandra 1.1.2

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();
String data = "CREATE COLUMNFAMILY user_count(priKey text PRIMARY KEY, countME counter)";
st.execute(data);
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:        
org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: Cannot add a counter column   
(countme) in a non counter column family

'CREATE COLUMNFAMILY user_count(priKey text PRIMARY KEY, countME counter)'
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.doExecute(CassandraStatement.java:179)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraStatement.execute(CassandraStatement.java:203)
at cassandratest.EdgeCreator.aaListData(EdgeCreator.java:1323)
at cassandratest.Main.main(Main.java:214)
```

I have tried the answer to [Cassandra cql comparator type counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813211/cassandra-cql-comparator-type-counter?rq=1) but I understand that default_validation for CQL 3.0.0 is no longer useable.  I have searched the documentation but have found nothing.  I am looking how to create a counter column family and increment it, using Java.
Thanks for the help in advance!

This is also my first post on here, so please let me know if there is anything wrong with it so I can correct it in the future.

**Update**
When using the CREATE statement in cqlsh, I get a ConfigurationException.  The cqlsh session follows:

```
Connected to Test Cluster at localhost:9160.
[cqlsh 3.0.0 | Cassandra 1.1.0 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.30.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh> use "Keyspace2";
cqlsh:Keyspace2> CREATE COLUMNFAMILY user_count(priKey text PRIMARY KEY, countME
counter);
Bad Request: org.apache.cassandra.config.ConfigurationException: Cannot add a 
counter column (countme) in a non counter column family
cqlsh:Keyspace2>
```

Comment: Works for me in Cassandra 1.2.2, `cqlsh -3`: `CREATE COLUMNFAMILY user_count(priKey text PRIMARY KEY, countME counter);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you're using cql 3? It looks from your traceback like you're not, and that's the error I would expect if you were accidentally using cql 2.

That create statement should work in cql 3.

**Edit:** You were using cql 3, but you weren't using Cassandra 1.1.2.  That was a known bug with 1.1.0; it should be fixed if you upgrade to 1.1.2.

Comment: I have updated everything to the latest releases and changed the connection statement to include the CQL version number:  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/Keyspace2?version=3.0.0"); And when I start the program it says that it is using CQL version 3.0.0

Comment: No, I get the same error about not being able to add a counter column in a non counter column family.  However, when I log into cqlsh (which I had not done after I updated everything) it says that it is running cqlsh 2.2.0

Comment: Use the cqlsh -3 option to get cql 3.

Comment: I am still getting the same error even with 3.0.0.  And I am now sure that I am using 3.0.0 because I now have to put quotes around my keyspace which has capital characters, along with it specifying that it is 3.0.0.  I am stumped :-\

Comment: Do you mean that the CREATE command is failing, even under cqlsh -3?

Comment: Please edit the post and paste the entire cqlsh session, if you could. That sounds like a bug.

Comment: Just FYI, I am running this on windows and I could not run cqlsh -3 but I opened up the cqlsh file and changed the default version from 2 to 3, so it will always run 3.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you're using Cassandra 1.1.0, not 1.1.2. That's probably it- I'll do a test on 1.1.0 to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, your right.  When I tested out the command directly on cqlsh, I downloaded the latest Datastax Community Server and it came with 1.1.0.  I guess they have not updated the download package.  However, I know I am running 1.1.2 with my Java program (different folder than the Community Server).  I have double checked the libraries and JDBC driver but am still getting the same error.  I pointed the cqlsh shell at the cqlsh file, in the 1.1.2 folder but it still says 1.1.0

Comment: Cqlsh is getting that version number from the Cassandra instance it's pointing at, not its own source. And it shouldn't matter if you're using cqlsh from 1.1.0 or 1.1.2- the Cassandra it's connecting to is definitely 1.1.0.

Comment: I will check that my version is the latest and everything is up to date.  Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @thepaul Do you mind updating your answer? It's now somewhat backwards which, IMO, makes it a bit unclear. It seems like a great demonstration of finding a bug but could be updated to be clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. What's backwards?